# Find (Guess) the explicit formula of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Le $ b_0, b_1, b_2, ...$ be the sequence defined recursively as

$b_0 = 0, b_k = k - b_{k-1} $ for each integer $k >= 1 $

Which gives,

$b_0 = 0$

$b_1 = 1$

$b_2 = 1$

$b_3 = 2$

$b_4 = 2$

$b_5 = 3$

$b_6 = 3$

$b_7 = 4$

I've gotten $ \frac 14 (2n - 1^n + 1)$ but this doesn't work for $b_1$

Comment: It's basically $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$

Comment: Try $b_n=\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil$; you can prove it by induction. It helps to prove first that $b_{n+1}=b_n$ when $n$ is odd, and $b_{n+1}=b_n+1$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Would that count as an 'explicit' formula?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the proof.

Comment: I suppose a typo in your last formula ($-1^n=1$). It should be $\frac 14 (2n - (-1)^n + 1)$ which works for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$b_k = \frac{2k+\left(1-(-1)^n\right)}{4} \Rightarrow \{b_{2n}=n \space\,,\space b_{2n+1}=n+1 \}$

$b_0 = \frac{0+(1-1)}{4}=\frac{0+0}{4}=0$

$b_1 = \frac{2+(1+1)}{4}=\frac{2+2}{4}=1$

$b_2 = \frac{4+(1-1)}{4}=\frac{4+0}{4}=1$

$b_3 = \frac{6+(1+1)}{4}=\frac{6+2}{4}=2$

$b_4 = \frac{8+(1-1)}{4}=\frac{8+0}{4}=2$